# mybatis @Update not working properly

Tags: java, sql-update, mybatis

```
@Update("UPDATE TABLE_ROUTE SET TABLE_CODE =#{tableCode}, ACTIVE =#{active}, ROUTE_ID =#{routeId} WHERE TABLE_CODE=#{tableCode}")

int updateTableRoute(TableRoute tableRoute);
```

This gave me an error saying:

> "Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2".

which is right.

Now i changed this statement to:

```
@Update("UPDATE TABLE_ROUTE SET TABLE_CODE =#{tableCode}, ACTIVE =#{active}, ROUTE_ID =#{routeId} WHERE TABLE_CODE=#{tableCode} and ROUTE_ID =#{routeId}")

int updateTableRoute(TableRoute tableRoute);
```

This is still giving me the same error:

> "Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2".

Could anyone help me out with this?

> table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE "HIE"."TABLE_ROUTE" (  
  "TABLE_CODE" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "ROUTE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "ACTIVE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "INSERT_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "INSERT_BY" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "UPDATE_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
  "UPDATE_BY" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE));
```

Comment: How does your table look like? What columns does it have and what are their types?

Comment: Add it to the body of the question.

Comment: How are you calling these methods?  You shouldn't get any result set returned from an update method.